# eth0 and wlan0 not working together

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, ethernet

ubuntu14.04 i made as accesspoint.And receiving data wirelessly. but whenever i am connecting ethernet cable, ubuntu is not receiving any wifi data. This same set up used to work earlier before i changed the networking files. Can anyone help. I am using edit connection option at top right side to edit IP for wired ethernet connection. ifconfig gives ip addresses of wlan0 and eth0.

Comment: "This same set up used to work earlier before i changed the networking files" - does it work again if you revert your changes?

Comment: no it doesnt work though i revert back the changes

Comment: Any further suggestions please?

Comment: Yes: provide more detail. Which "networking files"? What exactly did you change (and why)?

Comment: Can you please go thru this linkhttps://askubuntu.com/q/1061480/855548               I have started all afresh the whole setup. The link gives the current scenario. Can u pls help\

Comment: danzel, Did you see the link? Can u help

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the relevant information there.

Comment: Danzel, can you please look into this please https://askubuntu.com/q/1062749/854819