# systems in wired and wireless connecteion receive data wirelessly but not wired in web browser

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I have 2 ubuntu systems in LAN connected wirelessly as well as with wired ethernet cable. One is ubuntu 14.04 which i have made as accesspoint. And the other is 16.04 made as base station.
1. The a.p assigns 10.42.0.1 as its ip and the other i have given static ip address as 10.42.0.88 to the base station using "ifconfig wlp6s0 10.42.0.88 up".
2. The ip address of the same 2 system wired ethernet  are set as 10.42.0.15(a.p) and 10.42.0.50 (base sation) using "ifconfig enp7s0 10.42.0.15 up"
the same settings i have given in "edit connection" in gui.

when ifconfig command is run on both the systems they show the assigned ip addresses and they ping each other.
The base station is receiving data wirelessly from an embedded systems (transmitting data thru wifi). (the base station has a c program running on it to receive wifi data and web server program to transmit the 
same data at port 8080). This wireless data recievd data  i want to view
through ethernet cable in the a.p in web explorer using "10.42.0.50:8080". But i am not able to view the data.  Can anyone help? is networking setting an issue?

Comment: I don't understand why they are connected both with ethernet *and* wireless.  Usually, ethernet is easy and faster. Are they also connected to a router or switch? Is Network Manager running on either or both? Please clarify.

Comment: Actually wirelessly a system is working as t p

Comment: Actually wirelessly a system is working as tcp server  and through wired Ethernet as webserver.it is our requirement and application.they aren't connected thru router or switch. Through network manager's edit connection i programmed one system as a.p.in the base station I used ifconfig command to program the ips .

Comment: Chili555 can you please dig into it a little more

Comment: I regret that I haven't any other suggestions.